# While Using a Print Functionality in Windows Universal App in Windows-10 ,the PrintingRoot.Children.Add(firstPage) Getting Null exception Error

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal

I am implementing a print functionality which has almost done but when  clicking on the the print button its throw a null exception in the  `PrintingRoot.Children.Add(firstPage)`.

Code:

```
protected override void PreparePrintContent()
{
    try
    {
        trys = trysgetorderdetail;
        OrderDetailResponse obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderDetailResponse>(trys);
        if (firstPage == null)
        {
            firstPage = new popup(obj1);
        }

        PrintingRoot.Children.Add(firstPage);
        PrintingRoot.InvalidateMeasure();
        PrintingRoot.UpdateLayout();
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {

    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}

protected virtual Canvas PrintingRoot
{
    get
    {
        return FindName("printingRoot") as Canvas;
    }   
}
```

So suggest me a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be many causes for null reference exceptions depending on your code path. And the solution of this exception should be found with debugging.

What I would do would be:

- check if `PrintingRoot` is null
- check if `PrintingRoot.Children` is null
- continue like this if there exists paths that we don't see here.

You can check like below:

```
if(PrintingRoot == null) throw new Exception("PrintingRoot object is not set");
if(PrintingRoot.Children == null) throw new Exception("PrintingRoot.Children object is not set");
```

Afterwards you should set an instance to the handle you've found accordingly.

**Update**:
Now you know what is null. Appearently `FindName("printingRoot") as Canvas` is not returning any valid object.

Therefore the reason is probably that your `Canvas` objects name is either empty, or it is something else. Make sure you typed it correctly. Below is an example.

```
<Canvas Name="PrintingRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="215,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

Mind the `Name` attribute!

Comment: I have just tried  and it throw the "PrintingRoot object is not set" exception so please suggest a solution of it.

Comment: I also checked in the FindName("printingRoot") method in that i got a null Print root exception.                                                                                Code is below:                                                                                                                                    protected virtual Canvas PrintingRoot
        {
            get
            {
                Canvas temp= FindName("printingRoot") as Canvas;
                return FindName("printingRoot") as Canvas;
            }
            
        }

Comment: I  tried  everything but i did not get any solution.so if you have any solution then tell me.

Comment: Thank You Tolga Evcimen for Giving me  time and solve my query.

Comment: You're welcome. You may think to give an upvote too! :)